# Click button to pop up new window with random color on python 3

Tags: python, tkinter

We were planning to play colored Jenga with my kids and realized that we lost a dice with three colors (yellow, blue, red). I decided to write a program to generate random three colors. My program does not open a new window.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
def get_color():
  a = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow']
  print(random.choice(a))
Button(text='Select Color', command=get_color).pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: please post the code for `mainloop`

Comment: You also want to say `return random.choice(a)` instead of printing it to the console.

Comment: This question shows zero signs of doing any research or trying to solve the problem yourself before asking a question. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic implementation of what you described, you can improve on it as you see fit:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def set_color():
  root.configure(background = random.choice(['blue', 'red', 'yellow']))

root = Tk()
root.title("Random Color Tool")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 400))

button = Button(root, text="Generate Random Color", command=set_color)
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)   

root.mainloop()
```

**Screenshot of how it looks after pressing the button on Windows 10:**

[image: Random Color Tool Screenshot]